# Different texts from almost identical images with Tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have two images that are almost identical:

other.png

[image: other.png]

title.png

[image: title.png]

I use with Python script to extract the texts with Tesseract:

```py
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

def process(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
    # cv2.imshow('image', image)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    results = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='')
    print(path, results)

process('title.png')
process('other.png')
```

Here is the output:

```
title.png ‘CP TOOL
other.png cP TOOL
```

**I don't get the same results. Why? How I improve text recognition?**

The images are really small but I have no control over the system that generates the images. I have tried to increase the sizes of the images before processing them:

```py
    factor = 4
    width = int(image.shape[1] * factor)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * factor)
    dim = (width, height)
    image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Texts from these two images are extracted properly but I have other images (not enclosed here) that still get similar issue (*CP* being recognized as *cP* in particular).

I have tried to erode/dilate the image with no interesting effects but I have very new to OCR so I probably don't do things correctly...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OCR systems are not perfect but there are several things you can make to improve result based on your use case:

- You try to improve input image quality before using tesseract
- You can change the config in the `image_to_string` function
- You can retrain tesseract for a new fonts
- You can try another OCR system
- You can train your custom computer vision model

I recommend checking tesseract documentation https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc for more information about improving quality, config options and retraining tesseract